# how to make dynamic keyboard. When i click from keyboard all key text will change

Tags: android, input, ime, android-input-method

I am making now Input method services my question how to change text in key when i touch one key.
I have already array like :

```
String [] textDynamic = new String[] { "a", "b" ,"i", "c" .....}
```

This array load when i touch any key on keyboard all text will appearing in my keyboard keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use this code in `onKey()` method of your `InputMethodService` after you have committed the current key.

```
@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] ints) {
    -----
    -----
    conn.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);

    List<Keyboard.Key> keys = kv.getKeyboard().getKeys();

    for (Keyboard.Key key : keys) {

         // you can set any codes & labels to the all the keys in this loop
         // this is just an example of how it's done...
            key.codes = new int[]{12, 13, 14};
            key.label = "P";

     }

    -----
    -----
}
```

If one key has only one character, the codes array will have only one int.

You can merge this with your logic to generate random keys from your array.

Hope this helps.